# How can I remove HTML tags in Java?

Tags: java, regex, html-parsing

I need to remove the HTML tags from the following string in java

```
String text = "<html><head></head><body>hi x>a and y<b and z>c</body></html>";
```

I can do this with regular expressions. But it also removes the "b and z" in the string. Because it is consider this as tag.

Comment: where is "b and z" in String text = "hi x>a and yc" ?

Comment: It all starts with putting some thought and effort into your questions and at least getting the name of the programming language right in the title of the question. Congratulations, you've rediscovered that [the center cannot hold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: y<b and z>c cjeck before the </body> tag

Comment: why even answer this, it should just be marked a duplicate to close and move on!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: NOT a dupe of that question. The OP seems to be looking for a way to that removes HTML but does not remove (improper) usage of raw `<`. However, regex is the wrong answer here of course.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it will remove "b and z".  It is *supposed to* remove that text.  Because in HTML attributes do not have to be quoted and they do not need values.  So `b` is an element and `and` and `z` are attributes (without values).  That is what an HTML parser would recognize.

Of course, `and` and `z` and not really acceptable attributes for the `b` element, but in terms of syntactic well-formedness you should recognize the `b` as an element.

If you did not want that removed, you need to write your `<` as `&lt;`.  That is how to write correct HTML anyway. :)

**ADDENDUM**

(Yes I am aware of the famous "can't parse HTML with a regex" answer cited above in the comment, but the `<` vs `&lt;` in the question was worth pointing out in an answer, IMHO.)

Comment: There is Java library called TagSoup (http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) which is very good at cleaning up bad HTML, but it interprets the `b` as an element just like Ray Toal describes. Its interpretation is `<html><head></head><body>hi x&gt;a and y<b and="and" z="z">c</b></body></html>`, which is correct but obviously not what you want.